# Is $\mathbb{N} $ order isomorphic with $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, set-theory, ordinals, well-orders

$(X, \le) $ and $(Y, \le')$ be two well ordered sets.

$f:X\to Y$ with

i) $f$ is bijective.

ii) $a\le b \implies f(a) \le' f(b) $ $(\forall a, b\in X) $

is said to be an order isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$.

> $X=\mathbb{N}$ and $Y=\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$

> $\le$ : usual ordering in $\mathbb{N}$.

> $n< {\infty}$ ,$\forall n\in {\mathbb{N}}$

> Both are well ordered sets.

> Question : Is there any order isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$?

(*Proof by contradiction*) : Assume $\exists f:X \to Y $ an order Isomorphism.

Then, there exists an unique $u \in X$ s.t. ${f(u) =\infty}\in Y$

Since, $X$ is not bounded above, we can find an element  $v$ s.t. $u<v$ (in that case we can choose $u+1$)

$u+1 \in X \implies f(u+1) \in Y \setminus \{\infty\}$

And, $f(u+1) < \infty =f(u) $

So, $\exists  u+1 \in X$ s.t $u<u+1$ but $f(u+1)<f(u) $.

Hence, the contradiction.

Is my proof correct? Or, is there an other way to proof this? Thanks.

Comment: You didn't actually state what you're proving (that there is no such isomorphism), but yes, the proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you sir.   I will try to cover mistake from next time.